# Bestseller Products Collection Not coming zero for current month and day even it is using old collection magento 2?

Tags: magento2, best-seller

> Here Bestseller Products Collection Not coming zero for current month
>   or day because for this month or day we don't have any orders even it
>   is using old records  and showing some number of data in magento 2??

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
   protected $_collectionFactory;
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
   ) { 
       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

    public function getBestSellerData(){

        $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                    ->setPeriod('day') //you can add period daily,yearly
                    ->setPageSize(8);            

        return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;

    }


}
```

Comment: i have updated the answer please check the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
   protected $_resourceFactory;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory $resourceFactory
   ) { 
       $this->_resourceFactory = $resourceFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

    public function getBestSellerData(){
       //implemented logic based on reports

        $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_resourceFactory->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection');
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->setPageSize(8);

        echo count($bestSellerProdcutCollection);
        return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;

    }


}
```